# Printing christmas tree in python

Tags: python, for-loop

How can I make a perfect Christmas tree in python? i have here my code but its not working well, it needs to print `'~~'` in the first for loop.

```
height = 7
for a in range(1, (height + height) - 3):
    if a % 2 != 0:
        if a == 1:
            print(a * 'o')
        else:
            print(a * '* ')
for a in range(height + 1):
    if a % (height + 1) == 1:
        test = height - 3
        print(test * '~~' + a * '|' + test * '~~')
    if a % (height + 1) == 1:
        test = height - 3
        print(test * '~~' + a * '|' + test * '~~')
```

Output of my code is:

```
o
* * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~
```

my desired output is:

```
~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~* * *~~~~~~
~~~~* * * * *~~~~
~~* * * * * * *~~
* * * * * * * * *
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code a little bit, well here's the code:

```
height = 7
z = height - 3
x = 1
for i in range(1, (height + height) - 3):
    if i % 2 != 0:
       if(i==1):
          print('~~' * z + 'o' +'~~' * z)
       else:
          print('~~' * z + '* ' * (x-1)+ '*' *1 +'~~' * z)
       x+=2
       z-=1
for a in range(height + 1):
    if a % (height + 1) == 1:
       test = height - 3
       print(test * '~~' + a * '|' + test * '~~')
    if a % (height + 1) == 1:
       test = height - 3
       print(test * '~~' + a * '|' + test * '~~')
```

Output:

```
~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~* * *~~~~~~
~~~~* * * * *~~~~
~~* * * * * * *~~
* * * * * * * * *
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is what i'm looking for. actually i already get the formula for printing the '~~' but i can't add it inside the for loop because its also for loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
def values():
    yield 'o'
    for i in range(3, 10, 2):
        yield ' '.join('*' * i)
    yield from '||'

for v in values():
    print('{:~^17}'.format(v))
```

Prints:

```
~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~* * *~~~~~~
~~~~* * * * *~~~~
~~* * * * * * *~~
* * * * * * * * *
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~
```

---

Or:

```
for v in ['o'] + [' '.join('*' * i) for i in range(3, 10, 2)] + ['|', '|']:
    print('{:~^17}'.format(v))
```

Comment: thanks, your code actually works, but for me as a beginner, i can't still understand some function like yield.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the `string` method `center`.

```
for x in range(1, 30, 2):
    s = '*' * x
    print(s.center(30))

              *               
             ***              
            *****             
           *******            
          *********           
         ***********          
        *************         
       ***************        
      *****************       
     *******************      
    *********************     
   ***********************    
  *************************   
 ***************************  
***************************** 
>>>
```

EDIT: Including the tildes.

```
limit = 30

for x in range(1, limit, 2):
    tildes = '~' * ((limit-x)//2)
    out = tildes + '*' * x + tildes
    print(out)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~***~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~*****~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~*******~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~*********~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~***********~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~*************~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~***************~~~~~~~
~~~~~~*****************~~~~~~
~~~~~*******************~~~~~
~~~~*********************~~~~
~~~***********************~~~
~~*************************~~
~***************************~
*****************************
```

Comment: Should also pass "~" as the second argument fillchar.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code just a little:

```
height = 7
width = 17
for a in range(1, (height + height) - 3):
    if a % 2 != 0:
        if a == 1:
            sym = 'o'
            curly = ''.join(['~' for i in range((width-len(sym))//2)])
            print(curly +  a * sym + curly)
        else:
            sym = a * '* '
            curly = ''.join(['~' for i in range((width - len(sym)) // 2)])
            print(curly + sym + curly)
for a in range(height + 1):
    if a % (height + 1) == 1:
        test = height - 3
        print(test * '~~' + a * '|' + test * '~~')
    if a % (height + 1) == 1:
        test = height - 3
        print(test * '~~' + a * '|' + test * '~~')
```

```
~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~
~~~~~* * * ~~~~~
~~~* * * * * ~~~
~* * * * * * * ~
* * * * * * * * * 
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~
```

It's not perfect but no Christmas tree is 100% straight.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple programming problem. So let's create a simple program for solving it.

First, we need to draw our tree. in each line, our tree has an odd number of starts for showing tree and some `~` characters for representing the background. If we want to have a tree which its height is equal to the `height` variable. at the `height`th line, we don't want to have any `~` character. But in the first line, we want to have only one `*` character.

So it seems to be a good idea to having a for loop that counts from `height` to the zero and relates the number of `~` characters somehow to it.

Let's see the code first:

```
for i in range(height, 0, -1):
    print("~" * (i - 1))    // repeating `~` character (i - 1) times
```

If you run this code, you will get the following output:

```
~~~~~~
~~~~~
~~~~
~~~
~~
~
```

Now let's add the `*` characters for drawing the tree. We should have the exact opposite relation for `*` characters from `~`.

```
for i in range(height, 0, -1):
    print("~" * (i - 1), end="")
    print("*" * (((height - i) *2) + 1))
```

We add `end=""` at the end of the previous `print` function. Because `print` will add a newline character at the end in each call and we want to prevent it (because we want to add `*` characters after `~` characters).

Then we want to add `*` characters at each line. But we want to count their number
for 1 to `height * 2`. But we only need the odd numbers. That's what we did in the second line. Now, we have the following number of `*` characters at each line: 1, 3, 5, 7,...

Below is the output of that code (We considered that `height = 7`):

```
~~~~~~*
~~~~~***
~~~~*****
~~~*******
~~*********
~***********
*************
```

As you can see, now we have our Christmas tree. But our background is incomplete.
The only thing we should do is to repeat our first `print` statement. But this time we should not add `end=""` because we want that newline at the end of each line.

```
for i in range(height, 0, -1):
    print("~" * (i - 1), end="")
    print("*" * (((height - i) *2) + 1), end="")
    print("~" * (i - 1))
```

Now our tree is complete:

```
~~~~~~*~~~~~~
~~~~~***~~~~~
~~~~*****~~~~
~~~*******~~~
~~*********~~
~***********~
*************
```

You can add other things to your tree by following this simple approach. I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for the idea mate! i just started learning python last week. thanks for sharing that idea!

Answer (score 0):

Try using more conditionals to handle the number of stars (*). Drop a comment below if that doesn't work.

Like, you could do:

if '1star' do this..:
elif '2stars' do this..:

Answer (score 0):

I would code it like this:

```
sky=8
tree=1
for i in range(0,5):
    if i==0:
        print(sky*'~'+tree*'o'+sky*'~')
    else:
        print(sky*'~'+tree*'*'+sky*'~')
    sky-=1
    tree+=2
sky=8
tree=1
for i in range(0,2):
    print(sky*'~'+tree*'|'+sky*'~')
```

I modified the Christmas tree so that it looked thinner.

Comment: The 'sky' variable is the number of "~"s on both sides, and the 'tree' variable is the number of  "*"s or "o"s in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
var = 14
for i in range(1, var + 1):
    print(" " * (var - i) + "*" * i + "*" * (i - 1))
```

Sample output:

```
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
```

---

---

---

---